# MySQL Sum grouping issue

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table containing jobs to be invoiced. Each row contains two columns, 'value' and 'group'. Like this

```
ID   Value  Group
1   2000.00   1
2   2000.00   1
3   1000.00   0
4   1000.00   0
```

What I need to do is combine the values in Rows 1 and 2 (because they have the same group number), then return rows 3 and 4 as normal (so, not grouped together):

```
4000    //Rows 1 and 2 combined
1000    //Row 3 returned as whole value
1000    //Row 4 returned as whole value
```

I've tried to use `GROUP BY` in the query, so something like

```
  SELECT SUM(Value) AS totalValue FROM table GROUP BY Group
```

However this returns

```
4000
2000 //Row 3 and 4 combined
```

It's combining Row 3 and 4 because they share the same Group number, its grouping them together.

My problem is, I don't want them grouped together. I want them to return separately as they have a value of zero. Is there any way for me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Group AS Unique_ID, SUM(Value) AS totalValue FROM table WHERE Group>0 GROUP BY Group
UNION
SELECT id AS Unique_ID, Value As totalValue FROM table WHERE Group=0
```

Comment: Hi Aziz, thanks for the speedy reply. Unfortunately, this is only returning `4000 1000` instead of `4000 1000 1000`. Why is this?

Comment: That's because you need to select another column that will make each row unique ... I have updated the query.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out too! Thanks kindly for your help Aziz :-)